# jQuery selector: exclusive OR

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm using a set of jQuery selectors to insert some content on a number of different pages; however some pages feature more than one of the selectors, so the content is inserted more than once on the page. For example:

```
$('div.rColInnerL:first, div.box300.bdr.search:first, h2.blt13:first').before('<div>Hello World!</div>');
```

Is it possible to use a kind of exclusive-OR in the jQuery selector, to say that only one of these should be used? Many thanks.

Comment: Could you expound a bit on what you're trying to achieve? What is the exact behavior and what are you expecting?

Comment: It seems like his divs can have one or more of the classes, and therefore may be selected more than once.

Comment: Yes, but when he says `only one of these should be used`, it's difficult to say whether he means the first (which can be found using `first()`) or the one most relevant to that page, or whatever.

Comment: Sorry about that, in most circumstances there will only be one of the applicable divs on a page, but there was an edge case where 2 existed. In this case using .first() solves it, since I'm not too fussed about the order, mostly just avoiding multiple selections on a page. Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can reduce the set of found elements to the first one:

```
$('div.rColInnerL:first, div.box300.bdr.search:first, h2.blt13:first')
.first()
.before('<div>Hello World!</div>');
```

Comment: This works only if the order of the selector is the same as the potential order on the page. In OP's case it is further complicated because it isn't an issue of an element existing or not, but rather an issue of it existing, but for another purpose not applicable to the purpose of the selection.

Answer (score 4):

On the surface it would seem like you could use the [`first()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/first/) method to get the first match.

```
$('div.rColInnerL:first, div.box300.bdr.search:first, h2.blt13:first').first()
```

Of course this will depend on the first one always being the correct one. Since it seems like there may be some variation in the use of the element that is matched by the selector, it may be an issue.

jQuery does not necessarily return the elements in the order of the selector, but rather in the order of their appearance on the page, so this doesn't necessarily replicate an "exclusive OR" behavior that  you're looking for.

To be more precise, you'd need something more explicit:

```
var el = $('div.rColInnerL:first');
if( !el.length ) {
    el = $('div.box300.bdr.search:first');
    if( !el.length ) {
        el = $('h2.blt13:first');
    }
}
```

---

Here's an example of jQuery not returning the elements in the order of the selector:

```
<body>
    <div id="first">first</div>
    <div id="second">second</div>
</body>
```

```
alert( $('#second, #first')[0].id ); // alerts "first" instead of "second"
```

Even though `#second` is first in the selector, the first match is shown as the `#first` element, because it comes first in the document.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/XxXXc/

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer doesn't work to me.

I used this:

```js
var container = $('div.rColInnerL:first')[0] || 
  $('div.box300.bdr.search:first')[0] || 
  $('h2.blt13:first')[0];

$(container).before('<div>Hello World!</div>');
```